# Domain name cannot be resolved / Nameserver issue?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

I am trying to setup a small Wordpress website: `anahatngo.org`, hosted on Vultr (Ubuntu w/ preinstalled Wordpress), having registered my domain name from Godaddy. What I usually do, when pointing to a hosting server, is I just change the A record on my DNS settings to point to my server IP, and it worked the first time. But we had some software issue with the server and decided to scrap it and spin up a new instance.

But this time I had a friend do the DNS remapping, who migrated all the default nameservers to Vultr nameservers, having deleted the original DNS records from Godaddy and migrating them to Vultr. But I somehow managed to switch back to the default Godaddy nameservers and have added an A record pointing to the server IP and a CNAME www record that points to my domain name (besides the default records that specify the 2 NS and the SOA record).

### The issue:

1. It has been 36 hours since I changed my domain nameservers to the default Godaddy NS but I keep getting `ping: anahatngo.org: Temporary failure in name resolution` whenever I try to ping it from my main workstation connected to my home network, even on different browsers.
2. I am having no issues pinging or opening the site using my mobile network. Even the customer service guys at Godaddy can view our website, but neither me nor my friend can open it.
3. I tried tracking the propagation at dnsmap.io and dnschecker and we keep getting unresolved at the same places as it were when we changed it back.

I am having a hard time figuring out what I am doing wrong, and I am asking for guidance. I am extremely sorry if this a noob question.

Comment: Maybe you have a caching problem on your devices ? Try with a random proxy to see if it opens and use some NS tools to check if the NS is actually working as needed. You can use the 1st option from here: http://dnstools.fastnext.com/

Comment: @Overmind, thanks for the speedy reply, really appreciate it. The diagnostics seem to be fine over at the link you mentioned. The 2 NS are all working fine. As for the caching issue: I had tried it with different browsers and even my phone browser hooked to my phone wifi: Unreachable when connected to wifi, opens fine on mobile network. Used incognito tabs in both cases.

Comment: Resolves fine here also. There's also the possibility of a bad routing between your network's devices and the target IP. You should do a traceroute from the affected devices towards the 207*** IP of the domain to see how it behaves.

Comment: Hi, I made a pastebin (by literally throwing security out the window). There are ping packet losses at undisclosed locations in the traceroute. I have also run an nslookup with google public dns and unfortunately that cant resolve anything. You can find my pastebin report here: https://pastebin.com/5Epcjh6i

Comment: Please post a traceroute result of something universal also, like towards 8.8.8.8.

Comment: Okay, so after tearing my hair out for quite a while, I figured and fixed the problem: It was because of a bad DNSEC digest. Sorry for bothering everyone. Also thank you @Overmind. This question can now be closed.

Comment: DNSSEC issues can easily be found using dnsviz.net which will display any kind of DNS misconfiguration. Do not use `ping` to troubleshoot DNS problems, but at least `dig`. Also do not "wait". There is no propagation in the DNS, contrary to an often repeated myth, you can query authoritative nameservers and see immediately the changes and what works or not. Caching does not play anything there (when using authoritative nameservers)